# Change index inside multi level hierarchy Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` that is multi level and having 2 levels named `Outer Groups, Inner Numbers`. I want to change the Index of `Inner Numbers`.

```
outside='g1 g1 g1 g2 g2 g2'.split()
inside='1 2 3 1 2 3'.split()
hier_index=list(zip(outside,inside))
hier_index= pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(hier_index)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,3), hier_index, ['a','b','c'])

df.index.names = ['Outer Group', 'Inner Numbers']
```

So my DataFrame ha outer `g1, g2` and inner `1,2,3   1,2,3`. I want to change the names of 
these  as I am trying to learn. I do not want any shortcuts , Waht I want ot learn is how to

1. change `g1,g2` into `X,Y`
2. Change `g1(123)` -> `X(a,b,c)`
3. Change the label of columns such as `Outer Groups` -> `Level 1` and `Inner Numbers -> Level 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rename` with dictionary and specify levels, for change index names is possible use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.rename({'g1':'X','g2':'Y'}, level=0)
df = df.rename({'1':'a','2':'b', '3':'c'}, level=1)
df = df.rename_axis(['Level 1','Level 2'])
print (df)
                        a         b         c
Level 1 Level 2                              
X       a       -1.085631  0.997345  0.282978
        b       -1.506295 -0.578600  1.651437
        c       -2.426679 -0.428913  1.265936
Y       a       -0.866740 -0.678886 -0.094709
        b        1.491390 -0.638902 -0.443982
        c       -0.434351  2.205930  2.186786
```

Or create new `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and reassign back (lengths of both lists for new levels has to be same like original):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['X','Y'], ['a','b','c']], names=['Level 1','Level 2'])
df.index = mux
print (df)
                        a         b         c
Level 1 Level 2                              
X       a       -1.085631  0.997345  0.282978
        b       -1.506295 -0.578600  1.651437
        c       -2.426679 -0.428913  1.265936
Y       a       -0.866740 -0.678886 -0.094709
        b        1.491390 -0.638902 -0.443982
        c       -0.434351  2.205930  2.186786
```

Comment: Nice use of MultiIndex

Comment: @jezreal Thanks a lot... much appreciated